# Подстановка переменных при отправке почты

Tags: php, email

Делаю отправку почты (например, при смене пароля) где данные (аргументы) для функции **mail()**; берутся из базы данных. Это сделано для того, чтобы из админки была возможность редактировать текст сообщения. Проблема в том, что не могу заставить переменные в тексте сообщения подставляться автоматически. В каком виде хранить текст в базе? Где-то видел такую конструкцию: **идет текст *%переменная%* дальше текст**

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов:

- [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) для строки с переменными в виде $var. Строку обрамляете в `'echo "' . $var . '"'`;
- использовать функцию [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) с соответствующим форматом. Правда тогда переменные придется перечислять вторым и последующими аргументами ([`vsprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.vsprintf.php) принимает массив аргументов);
- более сложный: если на проекте используете шаблонизатор типа smarty, то использовать именно его. Только результат обработки шаблона не на экран выводить, а в переменную. Один из вариантов перехвата - [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php);

Answer (score 0):

Можно и так хранить в базе: `идет текст <:переменная:> дальше текст`. Можно и через проценты.

Делаешь выборку всего этого текста из базы в переменную, к примеру, `$template`.

Затем,

`$template = str_replace('<:переменная:>', $val //тут подставляешь свою переменную//, $template);`